# Weird behavior of long presses in Chrome and Firefox for Android

Tags: javascript, html, touch-event

So, I found some weird behavior of long presses in Chrome and Firefox for Android. I'm trying to avoid scrolling, context menus, vibration and selecting text. Also, I need the touch not to be canceled. I set a simple page like this:

```js
var logger = document.getElementById("logger")

function touchHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  logger.innerText += e.type + "\n"
}
function contextMenuHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  logger.innerText += e.type + "\n"
}

window.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler)
window.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler)
window.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler)
window.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler)
window.addEventListener("contextmenu", contextMenuHandler)
```

```html
<pre id="logger"></pre>
```

And I got these results, when pressing for a bit without moving the finger:

1. When I default prevent both touch events and the `contextmenu` event:

   - Chrome logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchend
     ```

     Note that Chrome vibrates at the same time `contextmenu` is fired.
   - Firefox logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchcancel
     ```

     Firefox cancels the touch event as soon as `contextmenu` is fired, which is a problem for me.
2. When I default prevent only touch events:

   - Chrome logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchend
     ```

     Nice. It dosen't vibrate.
   - Firefox logs the same thing.

     This time, it didn't cancel the touch, but it selected some text.
3.   When I default prevent only the
     `contextmenu`
     event:
   - Chrome logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchend
     ```

     It vibrates and scrolls, however.
   - Firefox logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchcancel
     ```

     Again, it's canceling the touch, but no text is selected.
4. Finally, when no events are default prevented:

   - Chrome logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchend
     ```

     And still vibrates and scrolls.
   - Firefox logs:

     ```
     touchstart
     contextmenu
     touchcancel
     ```

     Same thing :(

So, is there any way to prevent **scrolling, context menus, vibration and selecting text**, and to avoid Firefox **canceling the touch**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in future firefox mobile browsers:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1481923