# Detect a text selection on a smartphone

Tags: javascript, android, dom-events, smartphone

On Android Chrome, when selecting a text by long press, the events "touchend" and "touchstart" are not triggered.
The following solutions therefore do not work:

[How to detect a long touch pressure with javascript for android and iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139225/how-to-detect-a-long-touch-pressure-with-javascript-for-android-and-iphone)

Which event is triggered?

The "onselect" event seems to work only in inputs or textarea.

Answer (score 3):

The "selectionchange" event is working for : **Android (Chrome) and iOS (Safari)**.

The "contextmenu" event is working for : **Android (Chrome, Mozilla and Opera)**.

*For Mozilla and Opera you might need to wrap your function with a setTimeout:*

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', setTimeout(handleSelection, 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not a "mobile event", it is a good old contextmenu event who are fired :

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event

I have finally found the answer here : [Weird behavior of long presses in Chrome and Firefox for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55560929/weird-behavior-of-long-presses-in-chrome-and-firefox-for-android?rq=1)